# Stored procedure to process multiple records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to convert a stored procedure that takes one parameter in, and update a table column for a specific record, into a stored procedure that does the same update but in bulk.

Because there is a variable that gets set within the stored procedure code, when I remove the parameter, and run it, I get an error that reads:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I would like to ask for help, and learn how can I correctly transform my stored procedure from a parameter based, to a parameter-less code.

**UPDATED CODE**

This is my code that is failing:

```
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Desc  NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @DESC = 'Beginning of description ';
SET @Desc = @DESC+(
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN LEFT([pd].[Title], 1) = '"'
    THEN CONCAT('&quot;', REPLACE([pd].[Title], '"', ''), '&quot;')
  END
FROM [dbo].[Data_Feed] [df]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductData] [pd]
    ON [df].[sku] = [pd].[ProductID]
WHERE pd.ProductType IN (19, 20, 23, 26, 27));

SET @DESC = (
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN [df].[show] IS NOT NULL
    THEN CONCAT(@DESC, ' from ', [df].[show])
    ELSE CASE
           WHEN [df].[primary_performer] IS NOT NULL
           THEN CONCAT([df].[primary_performer], ' ', @DESC)
           ELSE CASE
                  WHEN [df].[performer] IS NOT NULL
                  THEN CASE
                         WHEN LEN([df].[performer])-LEN(REPLACE([df].[performer], ';', '')) > 1
                         THEN CONCAT(@DESC, ' by ', REPLACE(STUFF([df].[performer], LEN([df].[performer])-CHARINDEX(';',REVERSE([df].[performer]))+1, 1, ' and '), ';', ', '))                                                                                              
                         ELSE CONCAT(@DESC, ' by ', REPLACE([df].[performer],';', ' and '))                                                                                      
                       END
                  ELSE CASE                                                                              
                         WHEN [df].[composer] IS NOT NULL
                         THEN CASE
                                WHEN LEN([df].[composer])-LEN(REPLACE([df].[composer], ';', '')) > 1
                                THEN CONCAT(@DESC, ' by ', REPLACE(STUFF([df].[composer], LEN([df].[composer])-CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE([df].[composer]))+1, 1, ' and '),';', ', '))                                                                                                      
                                ELSE CONCAT(@DESC, ' by ', REPLACE([df].[composer], ';', ' and '))
                              END
                       END
                END
         END
  END
FROM [Data_Feed] [df]);

SET @DESC = @DESC+(
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN [df].[scoring] IS NULL
    THEN CONCAT(RTRIM(@DESC), '.')
    ELSE CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX(';', [df].[scoring]) > 0
           THEN CONCAT(' in ', LEFT([df].[scoring], CHARINDEX(';', [df].[scoring], 1)-1), ' format.')
           ELSE CONCAT('  in ', [df].[scoring], ' format.')
         END
  END
FROM [Data_Feed] [df]);

UPDATE [Data_Feed]
SET
  [description] = @Desc         

END;
```

Comment: Your select query is returning more than one record and failing while concatenating with @Desc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is what you're going for...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Update_Description

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE df SET
        df.[description] = CONCAT('Beginning of description ', CASE -- Why??? Both the "then" & "else" are the exact same...???
                                WHEN LEFT(pd.Title, 1) = '"'
                                THEN CONCAT('&quot;', REPLACE(pd.Title, '"', ''), '&quot;')
                                ELSE CONCAT('&quot;', REPLACE(pd.Title, '"', ''), '&quot;')
                            END)
    FROM 
        dbo.Feed df
        INNER JOIN dbo.Product pd
            ON df.sku = pd.ProductID
    WHERE 
        pd.ProductType IN (19, 20, 23, 26, 27);
END;
GO
```

Also, take a look at you're CASE expression, both the "then" & "else" are the exact same.

HTH, Jason

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for your help and your comment about the "then" & "else" being the same. I have a question, when I made the original post I just included one of the SELECT/ CASE statements that assign a value to the @Desc variable. What would it take to continue to use a variable and also have different SELECT/ CASE statements. I will update the stored procedure code to show you exactly what I have. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. :)

Comment: I opened a new question to be able to address these changes. Thank you.

Comment: I added  comment to the new post.

Comment: thank you, i am having trouble gathering the data you asked me for.

Comment: What sort of trouble are you having? If you can be specific, we can find a solution... Here's a good place to start... https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/